# Telethon async function to tkinter button

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

I have the this async function below and basically I wanna place It into the command of a button using tkinter.

```
async def main():
    await client.send_message('username', 'message')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

In `message` I wanna put the variable `cpf` of my code, but I don't know exactly how should place It all together. I'm very new with python, so sorry for anything wrong...

The code above is how I'm trying to do it, but It's running the function just when I run the code, and not when I press the `Button`. I'm getting `ValueError: The message cannot be empty unless a file is provided`

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from tkinter import *

api_id = xxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxx'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

code_entry = Entry(canvas)
code_entry.pack()

async def main():
    cpf = code_entry.get()
    await client.send_message('ConsignadoBot', cpf)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main)

search_btn = Button(canvas, text='Consultar', command=main)
search_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produces a completely different error before producing the one you claim to have.

```py
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main)
```

This line fails, because in [`loop.run_until_complete()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete), "an `asyncio.Future`, a coroutine or an awaitable is required":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 558, in run_until_complete
    future = tasks.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 619, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

The correct code would be:

```py
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Now, it will error with "empty message" because it's executing before the user enters anything.

---

This code:

```py
root.mainloop()
```

Is blocking. Telethon is an `asyncio` library, which means the event loop won't be running unless you do something else, which means Telethon won't be able to make any progress.

This can be solved by making it async:

```py
async def main(interval=0.05):
    try:
        while True:
            # We want to update the application but get back
            # to asyncio's event loop. For this we sleep a
            # short time so the event loop can run.
            #
            # https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/33ecpl
            root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except tkinter.TclError as e:
        if 'application has been destroyed' not in e.args[0]:
            raise
    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

---

For a more carefully designed `async`-friendly tkinter app, see [Telethon's `gui.py` example](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/04ba2e1fc7932fb6f0136c1e681d585fb452ce92/telethon_examples/gui.py).

Comment: I tried to understand and implement your solution but as I'm kind of new with programming I was not able to do It. I'v also entered in your Git Hub, tested your GUI and It's awsome!! It looks like what I wanna achieve, but even better! I'v tried to read the code and understand but I'v got very lost; Do you have any tips or docs for what I have to read and learn to achieve this?

Comment: I would say GUI are not an easy topic to learn programming with, at least not in my opinion and languages I know. I suggest learning to program Python first and try to tackle GUIs later.